# What kind of yellow flower is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany, flowers

Shot in a garden in Haliburton, Ontario, Canada on August 6th, 2020. Flowerhead size approx. 3" diameter across.

[image: Yellow Flower]

[image: Another angle]

Comment: It would be helpful to show the flower-head from a bee's eye view, perhaps the leaves too if you can.

Comment: Can unequivocally say *Asteraceae* from the picture. Beyond that, without more information, very hard to say. Likely a garden (cultivated) plant rather than  a wild species.

Comment: We serious gardeners call that a DYC: a damned yellow composite, because there are so damned many of them. Head on photo required, but I'd guess it was a single heliopsis. Leaves would help, too.

Comment: It's definitely heliopsis, probably [Heliopsis *helianthoides*](https://www.wildflower.org/plants/result.php?id_plant=HEHE5).